# WPF WrapPanel In a ViewBox maximum size

Tags: wpf, wrappanel, viewbox

In my program I have a WrapPanel inside of a viewbox. The WrapPanel (which is actually the ItemsPanelTemplate of an ItemsControl) contains some bound items that can all be different sizes.

```
<Viewbox Name="ViewWindow" Margin="10">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" MaxHeight="600"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The goal of all of this is that I would like for all of the items to be sized to fit on a single screen. The Viewbox handles this by zooming the contents so that they all fit. Each of the items in the WrapPanel is user defined text and so they can all be different sizes. What I am trying to accomplish with the WrapPanel is that the resulting text on the screen will be as large as possible. I have been doing this by setting the WrapPanel MaxHeight so that the items get wrapped into more columns if they are too tall, but this is kind of a hacky way to do it and I find for different groups of Items, the MaxHeight needs to be different.

As an example of what I mean by this imagine that the Items that the ItemsControl is bound to is simply displaying every letter in the alphabet. Without any way to force the items to wrap to multiple columns you would end up with one really tall column with really small text, but if we set the MaxHeight of the WrapPanel then we can force the Items to multiple columns like this and the text would be bigger on the screen:

```
A    F    K    P    U    Z
B    G    L    Q    V
C    H    M    R    W
D    I    N    S    X
E    J    O    T    Y
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a better control to use than WrapPanel? Do I need to create some kind of custom Panel to get what I want?

Thanks for any help you can offer

**Edit:**

For an example of why a UniformGrid wouldn't work, suppose I had these 5 items (with each letter representing a different item)

```
A    C    E
A    C    E
A    D    E
B    D    E
```

With a UniformGrid all the items would take the size of item E and it would all take up a lot more space on screen.

Comment: How about using a UniformGrid as your ItemsPanel? I *think* that will add rows and columns as you add items.

Comment: You won't be able to do this is any simple way.  If a wrap panel is inside a viewbox, it will never need to wrap because the viewbox shrinks it to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Does this achieve what you are trying to do:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Using your example alphabet, I get it laid out like this:

```
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
M N O P Q R
S T U V W X
Y Z
```

Now, if it's really important to you that they be arranged in columns rather than rows, then it's a little tricky. Here's a really hacky way to get them arranged by columns:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I don't *think* you can tell a uniform grid to arrange things column first.

Comment: Well, I don't think a UniformGrid will do what I need because the items will be different heights and I don't want them to all be layed out in a way where they will all take up as much space as the biggest item.

Comment: @aalex675: So you want to pack things in as close as possible with no semblance of order at all? Even you WrapPanel is going to have columns taking the width of the largest item in the column.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the width of the columns being equal, that is fine. I guess what I need is for the WrapPanel to figure out the best MaxHeight based upon the heights and widths of the items in it. I am starting to wonder if I could maybe just do this in a ValueConverter and just get the heights and widths of all the items in the Panel to figure it out.